# GWT css include with Client Bundle -> "No source code is available for type de.main.resources.ResourceBundle..."

Tags: css, gwt, resources, module, clientbundle

after running into some problems with the deprecated ways to include css resources into my application I'm eager about using ClientBundle to include the css files.

I added the following line to my *###.gwt.xml* file:

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.resources.Resources" />
```

I created an interface which looks like this:

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.resources.client.ClientBundle;
import com.google.gwt.resources.client.CssResource;

public interface ResourceBundle extends ClientBundle 
{
    public static final ResourceBundle INSTANCE = GWT.create(ResourceBundle.class);

    @Source("GWT_Chat.css")
    public CssResource css();
}
```

In my onModuleLoad() method I'm calling:

```
Window.alert(ResourceBundle.INSTANCE.css().getText());
```

My css file is a random css file without any of the possible gwt additions.

When calling the application in the browser, the error I face is:

```
[ERROR] [gwt_chat] - Line 33: No source code is available for type de.main.resources.ResourceBundle;
 did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

Is there anything I left out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to implement a Subtype of `CssResource` and return it:

```
public interface ResourceBundle extends ClientBundle 
{
    public static final ResourceBundle INSTANCE = GWT.create(ResourceBundle.class);

    @Source("GWT_Chat.css")
    public MyCssResource css();

    public static interface MyCssResource extends CssResource {
        String getText();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right, I didn't mention that in the description of the problem.

But I have found the problem causing the error:

The package the ResourceBundle class belongs to was not under *de.main.client* which is specified in the *###.gwt.xml* file

    <source path='client'/>

How trivial ;)